# Getting JSESSIONID from JIRA using RestAssured throwing unknown host error

Tags: jira, rest-assured

I have written a script using RestAssured to connect to Jira and get Session ID.  Below is my code.

```
public void getJIRACookieTest(){        
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "Host");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "PortNo");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyUserName","UserName");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword","Password");       
    Response res = given().header("Content-Type","application/json").
    when().
    body("{\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"test\"}").
    post("https://jira_url/rest/auth/1/session").
    then().extract().response();
    System.out.println(res.prettyPrint().toString());
}
```

Here am getting unknow host error message.

Then i tried Postman and its perfectly working fine. I just selected no authentication, Content-Type as applicatio/json and body with user details
`{\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"test\"}`
in postman.
Not sure why am getting unknown host when i try with RestAssured.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: Could you please add the error RestAssured is throwing?

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <title>Unknown Host</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="white" fgcolor="black">
    <h1>Unknown Host</h1>
    <hr/>
    <font face="Helvetica,Arial">
      <b>

Description: Unable to locate the server named "        <em>jira.XX.server.xxxxxx.com</em>
" --- the server does not have a DNS entry.  Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists.  Double-check the name and try again.      </b>
    </font>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Perhaps it is related to your proxy, have a look at this: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/596

Comment: Hi, May be its dump question how its working fine in Postman as haven't given any proxy details

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I gather that you are connecting w/o a proxy using Postman and this works.

You are setting an HTTPS proxy in your RestAssured test anyway:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "Host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "PortNo");
System.setProperty("https.proxyUserName","UserName");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword","Password");
```

You should be fine after removing these lines from your test.

Comment: Thanks mate for your help. Actually its problem with certificate.  i just registered certificate using keytool and its working fine.